# How to open tab in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular7, angular8

I am trying to open the tab by accessing the tabs element reference but not working. How can i access my tabs element reference. selectTab function already i have written.If we pass tab element reference tab will open. But it is not working.If anyone know please help to resovle this issue.

If i use ngif i am Getting selectTab undefined issue.

app.component.html:

```
<tabs #main>
<tab #subone>Content</tab>
<tab #subtwo>Content</tab>
</tabs>

<button (click)="opentab1()">Sub One</button>
<button (click)="opentab2()">Sub Two</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('main') main: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('subone') subone: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('subtwo') subtwo: ElementRef;

opentab1(){

 this.main.selectTab(this.subone);

}

opentab2(){

 this.main.selectTab(this.subtwo);

}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-n8qv2e?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

It depends about what you want to achieve

You can use:

```
window.open(this.url)
```

in the back.

Or using routing in angular, if you mean that:

**app-routing.modules.ts**:

```
{
    path: 'component/:id', component: your_component
}
```

**component.html**:

```
target="_blank" [routerLink]="['/component', '/']"
```

Or just using events:

**html**

```
(a (click)="goToLink("www.example.com")">example</a)
```

**ts**

```
goToLink(url: string) {
    window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

Or coding directly previous one:

```
(a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank">example</a)
```

Comment: I am getting selectTab undefined issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-n8qv2e?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

why not just use *ngIf?

```
<div *ngIf="tab==1">Content</div>
<div *ngIf="tab==2">Content</div>


<button (click)="opentab(1)">Sub One</button>
<button (click)="opentab(2)">Sub Two</button>
```

ts:

```
opentab(num) {
    this.tab=num; 
}
```

Comment: You can see my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-n8qv2e?file=src/app/app.component.ts